# "NT Kernel & System" + "ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x94"

Tags: windows-7, drivers, kernel, cpu-usage

for the past few days iam experiencing a strange issue, "System - NT Kernel & System" has 14% load on my CPU. I googled around and found out that it typically is a driver error... Problem is, i cant identify the program causing it.

I recorded 30s with Windows Performance Tool, didnt help me much, iam a novice with WPT...

Process Explorer shows me this "ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x94" when looking under Threads of "System - NT Kernel & System".

I hope someone can help me out, its really strange. Not only causes it 14% load, it also makes the PC ridiculously slow, it kinda lags/freezes for couple of seconds before opening a folder for example.

Win7 64bit Ultimate
i7 4790k
980ti

Thanks in advance

ps: Uploaded the 30s recording
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dWP85eoKok1cI3nrXEN66e4Kelg9R_BF

ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock+0x94:[Image of "System - NT Kernel & System" Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pet7p.png)

Comment: Can you confirm you have the latest networking drivers - http://support.killernetworking.com/software/

Comment: Can you also open Internet Explorer settings -> "Connections" tab -> "LAN Settings" -> Uncheck "Automatically detect settings". Ensure use configuration script is also disabled as I'm sure you don't need it.

Comment: I went to the site and installed Killer Control Centre Win 7 (although i had the newest version of my driver but still), and i did the Internet Explorer thing (although iam using Firefox..).

I had the feeling that the NT Kernel & System issue appears while/after using jdownloader (something with internet/ethernet...). Now, after i installed Killer Control Centre, it seems that it solved the issue BUT now i have a new load on my CPU, about 10%, called "services.exe". Process Explorer shows "ntdll. dll!RtUserThreadStart" under the Threads tab of services.exe. 

Makes me crazy :/